# biblatex - content of .bib-file breaks biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

- TeX Live 2013, last update was on 2013-08-20
- biblatex uses biber

I am experiencing a weird and terrible problem: I think the content of my .bib-file breaks biblatex/biber. When I run my biblatex style with my .bib-file generated by [Citavi 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citavi) on 2013-08-20, the bibliography does not get printed and the following code bit can be found in the .log-file:

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear-ibid.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
```

and later on:

```
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear-ibid.cbx
File: authoryear-ibid.cbx 2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
```

- When I run the full .bib-file with an MWE, I can reproduce it (see code bit above).
- When I edit the .bib-file to the one source in the MWE and run it, it works flawlessly. This is why I think something in the .bib-file breaks biblatex.
- I also compared the most recent .bib-file with one that worked from before via Notepad++'s Compare-plugin, but to the best of my knowledge everything is just fine in the most recent file.

=> Would anyone have a clue of what is going on here? I actually doubt that the content breaks biblatex but it's the next best conclusion I can make at this point.

I suppose I could upload the whole .bib-file and ask for someone to check it, but I can't imagine anyone would do that nor that Citavi suddenly got something wrong during the export. Plus I don't want to do that really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The export by Citavi was indeed buggy: A field called *Reihentitel* (German for `collectiontitle` I supose) was exported, but without its label `collectiontitle` although I specifically defined the field to be exported. That lead to a line in the .bib-file saying

```
= {Something something}
```

... and luckily there were 2 spaces in front of the equal sign instead of just 1. Think I'm still missing a deeper understanding if that was the cause or if I overlooked something else.

A funny morning.